# AD8055 supply voltage ambiguity

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to use AD8055 as a high frequency Voltage Feedback Op-Amp. in [its datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8055_8056.pdf)  , on page 1 the pinout shows a V- and a V+ (as expected in many Op-Amps). but in page 5 , the absolute maximum rating table shows that maximum power supply is +13.2v (only positive voltage). In almost all Op-Amp datasheets that I have seen, this is marked as +/-V.

My question is: If I want to use 12v supply, should I connect a -12v to V- pin or it (pin 4) should be simply grounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operating range is given on page 4 as +/-5V typical and +/-6V maximum.  The way the absolute maximum rating is shown as +13.2v doesn't matter too much (-6V to +6V is +12V total), it is 1.2V above the total supply range which is typical.

Also note that these opamps are voltage feedback (**not** current) although the specifications do suggest they provide similar capability to current feedback amps.

> The AD8055 (single) and AD8056 (dual) **voltage feedback** amplifiers offer bandwidth and slew rate typically found in current feedback amplifiers

If you want to use a 12V single supply then connect +12V to V+ and GND to V-.  There will be no -12V in this configuration.

Your other option is a split supply with +6V to V+ and -6V to V-.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the AD8055 the recommended operating voltage range of the part is +/-5V as shown below - with the possibility to operate it at up to +/-6V.

[image]

The absolute maximum voltage rating shown in the datasheet is the maximum total voltage across the V- to the V+ pin. (When operating the part normally at +/-5V this total voltage across the V- to V+ pins is 10V).

[image]

Note that you never want to operate the part at these absolute maximum ratings. It really is necessary to take heed of this statement from the data sheet:

> Stresses above those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings may cause
>   permanent damage to the device. This is a stress rating only;
>   functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions
>   above those indicated in the operational section of this specification
>   is not implied. Exposure to absolute maximum rating conditions for
>   extended periods may affect device reliability.